# Trouble with pagination wordpress category page

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories

I am in trouble with the category page in wordpress, I want to display the pagination and I used a method that works in other templates that I developed in the past.

I get the Category ID

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

Declare the pagination

```
    $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $wpquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'paged'=>$page
    ));
```

And after my Loop I show the pagination

```
    global $wpquery;
    if( $wpquery->max_num_pages >1){
      $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

      echo paginate_links( array(
     'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
     'format' => '?paged=%#%',
     'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
     'total' => $wpquery->max_num_pages
       ) );
   }
```

If you try to go here

```
http://192.185.20.70/~t1t/tobeus.it/category/press/
```

you can see that the first & second page works, the third shows a 404...

in the other categories like "events"

```
 http://192.185.20.70/~t1t/tobeus.it/category/events/
```

only the first page works...

I can't solve this strange problem!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with pagination in category template. 
Try to change 'format' parameter 'paged' of paginate_links function to any other.

Example:

Set other parameter name, for example 'newparam'

```
echo paginate_links( array(
...
'format' => '?newparam=%#%',
```

Then get it from your url

```
$page = (get_query_var('newparam')) ? get_query_var('newparam') : 1;
```

Also don't forget to declare 'newparam' in functions.php file 'add_query_vars_filter' function.

Other solutions didn't worked for me, but this one did. I cannot explain exactly why, but it might be that parameter 'paged' is used somewhere when the second page is loading or something..

In this example you will just use other variable name to pass page number, and when the other pagination page will load, you will assign that value to 'paged' again, so it will load correct data from database.

Comment: after a lot of time I've discover a solution !
[link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104294/paginate-links-outputs-extra-empty-pages-on-custom-loop)